# Does the Talmud discuss "Solomon's Pools"

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, beis-hamikdash, water, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I recall visiting [Solomon's Pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon%27s_Pools), located a bit south of Bethlehem, years ago, before it became "Area A". Wikipedia says:

> The water system based on Solomon's Pools has provided water to
>   Jerusalem, on and off, for two millennia, all until 1967. The Low
>   Level Aqueduct was the longest serving of the Jerusalem-bound ones. It
>   started at the lower pool and once it reached Jerusalem, it crossed
>   the Tyropoeon Valley over a bridge to find its way onto the Temple
>   Mount platform, where it ended inside the great cisterns hidden
>   underneath its surface.

Considering that this pool was an important water source for the Second Temple, I'm curious if the Talmud has made any reference to it and has any description of it that supplements what the Wikipedia article states. If so, provide source links, please.

Comment: @AlBerko On this site, there are numerous questions regarding places mentioned in the Talmud even if they are not necessarily halachically connected. In this question, the collection of water into the Bet Hamikdash certainly is highly halachically-based. If, perhaps, The Pools are mentioned in the Talmud, perhaps, it has more detail on how it was collected, where exactly it went, how it was used, etc. I can't say unless I know **if** it's mentioned and where.

Comment: @Al I’m with DanF here. Not everything has to have a Nafka Minah to be a good question or an on-topic one.

Comment: @AlBerko The Beit Hamikdash is an expression of Judaism and as such pretty much automatically on-topic. It's also, as DanF suggests, entirely reasonable to expect that any given aspect of the Beit Hamikdash may have been discussed in the Talmud, which is also an expression of Judaism and pretty much automatically on-topic.